# How to make header become static in the top

Tags: html, css

How can I make the header navigation look a like http://dipstrategy.com?

My navigation bar keeps moving down when I am scrolling it.

Anyone have suggestion?

Comment: Please provide the relevant code and/or a demo on jsfiddle.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=css+position+fixed

Comment: in your css, add this property `position: fixed; top: 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the menu should be fixed even when you scroll down then you have to use css property [postion:fixed](http://www.codeislove.net/2011/05/tutorial-css-fixed-position-property.html) and the demo site which you have provided did the same thing

```
<div id="top" class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="logo left">
            <img src="images/dipstrategy.png" alt="web agency">        </div>
        <div class="navigation right">
            <ul id="nav">
            <li class="margin-right15 current"><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
            <li class="margin-right15"><a href="#do">WHAT WE DO</a></li>
            <li class="margin-right15"><a href="#team">CORE TEAM</a></li>
            <li class="margin-right15"><a href="#work">WORKS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <br clear="all">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :-

```
#top {
    position: fixed;
    background: #1a1a1a;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    z-index: 1999;
}
```